# Ruby is getting wrong class name from my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, draper

Weird error, I'm calling `::Facility::ProcedureDecorator`, but for some reason on my staging server ruby wants to call `ProceduresDecorator` instead. Any ideas what is going on?

Here are some samples:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:0x00555f1ea188d0>::ProceduresDecorator
Did you mean? Facility::ProcedureDecorator
File "/app/app/admin/facility.rb" line 32 in edit


def edit
  @facility = Facility.includes([:documents, :procedures]).find(params[:id])
  @facility_documents = @facility.documents
  @possible_document_kinds = FacilityDocument.kinds.map { |k, _| [k.humanize, k] }
  @facility_procedures = ::Facility::ProcedureDecorator
                         .decorate_collection(@facility.procedures) # line 32
  @facility_info = ::Facility::InfoDecorator.decorate(@facility.info)
  @possible_procedures = @facility_procedures.map { |procedure| [procedure.name, procedure.id] }
  @templates = @facility.emergency_event_templates
  @white_label = @facility.white_label
end
```

Edit:
Thanks guys for help, at the end problem was within `config/environments/staging.rb`, those two lines caused a problem.

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
```

Comment: Could it be that you are short-cutting by declaring it as `class Facility::ProcedureDecorator` instead of `module Facility class ProcedureDecorator`?

Comment: Share facility.rb file to get better understanding.

Comment: It looks like the auto-loader is confused about where this is supposed to be defined. Is your staging server running in development mode for some reason? I'm not sure adding things to model classes is safe when they're automatically reloaded.

Comment: @tadman I believe there is a model `class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base` and a generic helper `module Facility` defined in the other place. Wins who is loaded first :(

Comment: Note the error says `uninitialized constant .... ProceduresDecorator` which is plural

Comment: If this is your actual code have you tried moving the the dot(`.`) up one line. Right now your sytnax seems incorrect. Either that or try passing the with option such as `decorate_collection(@facility.procedures, with: ::Facility::ProcedureDecorator)`. I think the plural issue is inference from the fact that you intend to decorate a collection (which is by nature more than 1)